# Trying to determine whether a file is encrypted of just binary

Tags: encryption, binary, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer a file from an application to learn more about the data it is storing on me. Based on the name, it appears to be XML data, but it is obviously either saved in binary or encrypted. I thought it may have been some form of .Net (or other) serialization, and have tried decoding it that way. But, no love. Inspection in hex has not given any clues either.

Maybe someone with more 'skilz' can give me some insight into it. [Here is the file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7332137/User.xml.dat)

Comment: Why would someone save the xml data in binary format?The idea to use XML is because they are readable to begin with

Comment: That's not a programming question.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Yes actually it is a programming question. I'm looking for where to start, as to writing an app that can open, edit, and save the file. But, figuring out the format is the first step. If it is encrypted, I can't do it. If it is a standard serialization of some sort I may be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voted down and answering: the file is exactly N * 16 bytes in size, does not contain any repetition as far as I can see, and it seems to be filled with random bytes. The first bytes seems completely random as well, hinting that this is not a plain protocol.

This would probably hint that the file is AES CBC encrypted. DESede (or any cipher with a 8/16 blocksize) could of couse also have been deployed. Without the key (if any) this all is not going to help you much (if it was, I would not be answering you).

Comment: Thank you for the response. There are a few other "xml" files as well. And when viewing them through a HEX editor, the first few bytes are the same some of those files. Now I would imagine that this is either some sort of header data, or because the file starts with the same data, and and is encrypted in a way that would cause it to be laid out the same.

Comment: If there are more 16 or 8 byte blocks repeated, then that is a sure sign of ECB mode encryption, if it is only at the start of the file, it's CBC encryption with a constant IV value (most likely zero's). That's a crypto weakness because it gives away information about the plain text, but you cannot use it to crack the full plain text or key.

Comment: Thanks owlstead. But, I'm not sure I fully understood your response.

Comment: The first bytes that are similar are:

A7 29 D0 83 BC 9A B4 7C 5D D1 D3 A3 E1 7A 57 64 87 C6 A6 B5 AB 6C C1 EA 19 D6 47 2E 8E FE AA 20 25 89 EC 90 DE 55 4C 61 81

Here is another file to illustrate: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7332137/UserExerciseData.xml.dat

Comment: After doing some more research. Your response made more sense. It looks like it may be AES, and at that a futile project to attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The entropy of first file is high above 7.7 that might indicate encryption. The first 28h bytes (320-bit) of the files match. Is that possible that's the key and the encoded data starts at 28h?

Comment: Not really sure. All of the files either start with these 32 bits:

A7 29 D0 83 BC 9A B4 7C 5D D1 D3 A3 E1 7A 57 64 87 C6 A6 B5 AB 6C C1 EA 19 D6 47 2E 8E FE AA 20


Or these 32 bits:

04 94 02 6F 5D 42 0F 62 EF 4C FC 9B 8E D5 E1 CC 13 27 C6 1E DB 2E 87 B4 86 AF 34 C8 0C 98 EE 0D

This is a little odd. Asuming the naming convention, and that it is indeed an xml file. the first line in the file would most likely be :

"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>"

Out of curiosity, how did you determine the entropy?

Comment: I think it is more likely that the file is CBC encrypted and that you are indeed looking at the XML header 'tag'. But it does not hurt to try it as the key, there have been USB stick vendors that prepended the key to the cipher text as well. More likely is the use of a hard coded key.

Comment: The XML tag you described is a bit longer (2bh) than the size of match (28h). The sizes however are very close so if the first 28h bytes represent the XML tag it seems to be a simple or weak encryption - is that something can you imagine? In that case I'd expect the bytes at the end of file to match because of the closing XML tag that should be the same but that's not the case.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback guys. @Attila, you make a good point about the ends not matching. I think if the file is encrypted, the chances of decryption it are slim. I was hoping that the file was just using some sort of object serialization that I had not been able to identify.